# AvalonEdit - How do i color variables inside of a string

Tags: nsis, avalonedit

Is there a way to add a rule in AvalonEdit to color all variables inside of a string to something different? Kind of like how NSIS does (HM NIS Edit for example)

In this case, i'd need to have "**$SmPrograms**" (a constant) and "**${AppName}**" (a variable) standout from the rest of the string.

```
Section "Start Menu Shortcuts" SecStartMenuShortcuts
  SectionIn 1 2
  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\Uninstall-${AppName}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" 0
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\MyApp.lnk" ; Delete older link if exists
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\MyApp2.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe" 0
SectionEnd
```

Many thanks if anyone can assist

Comment: "${AppName}" is a define, a variable would be $AppName...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest a ruleset within a span:

```
    <Span color="String">
        <Begin>"</Begin>
        <End>"</End>
        <RuleSet>
            <Rule foreground="#FF993366">
                \$[\w\d_]+
            </Span>
        </RuleSet>
    </Span>
```

Comment: Nicely done, Daniel! I goofed my RegEx, thanks for clearing that up